# How to identify clicked commandButton in my managed bean

Tags: jsf

I have an `actionListener` method in my managed bean which is called by many command buttons.

```
public void verifyTestDisponibility(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    if (button1 clicked) {
        // ...
    }
    if (button2  clicked) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The part I'm stucking at is identifying the clicked command button. How can I identify it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use it like this

In xhtml page we can use a `<h:commandButton>` tag with actionListener

```
<h:commandButton id="btn1" action="#{yourBean.method}" value="ButtonValue"
   actionListener="#{yourBean.commandClicked}"></h:commandButton>
```

In your managed bean

```
private String buttonId;
/* getters and setters for buttonId goes here */

public void commandClicked(ActionEvent event) {
  /* retrieve buttonId which you clicked */
  buttonId = event.getComponent().getId();

  /*check for which button you clicked*/
  if(buttonId.equals("btn1")){

  }else{

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `event.getComponent().getClientId();`

```
if (event.getComponent().getClientId().equals("firstButton")).....
```

Comment: thank you for replying , and event is it a javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent type?

Answer (score 0):

This works with ajax listener too. I had used with Primefaces 5 ajax listener. For example:

```
public void myListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent ev) {
  String clientId = ev.getComponent().getClientId();
  ...
}
```